# Two groups and their linear representations

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $G$ and $H$ be two (finite) groups. Let $V$(resp. $W$) be a linear representation of $G$($H$ resp.).
If $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic by $\phi$. How to describe the relationship between two representations?

In my opionin, $\forall g\in G, w\in W$, define $g\cdot w$ by $\phi(g)\cdot w$. And then we get two $G$-representations.

Is that OK? I tried to find some notes but failed.

By the way, the background of this question is following. I have a $G$-representation $V$ and two isomorphic subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$. I want to compare with the two restrictions.

Stupid question.

Comment: The only thing you can say is that the two representations are of isomorphic groups (which entails what you said). Otherwise there is no further relationship implied between the two representations.

Comment: Thank you very much